# email alert for customer on custom object

Tags: email, workflow, alert

Could you please help me with the below:

We have a custom object A containing fields of customer's name and email.
When a new record is created for object A, The customer should receive an email notification.

I suppose that here we need to use Process Builder. However I cannot realize how we can send email to customer as in email alert options I can see only internal users and 'related contacts'.

Could you please shere your ideas how such kind of workflows are working?
Thank you from the beginner :)

Comment: In the recipient type drop down of Email alert, you need to select Email field of Object A. Then use that email alert in your process builder.

Comment: This works really!

Comment: Glad to hear that. I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Pasting from comment:

In the recipient type drop down of Email alert, you need to select Email field of Object A. Then use that email alert in your process builder.

[image]

Comment: sorry frient, but i don't see where did you selected your Object A.